# XPS15 9570 with Pop!_OS won't boot after recent firmware update, will replacing new SSD save my machine?

Tags: firmware, pop-os

My machine was running Pop!_OS 20.04LTS. I had it running just fine for months except I couldn't update to nvidia driver 460. I did the firmware update around June of 2021, from that point onward my machine only boot into blank screen.

I went to Pop!_OS community at Facebook, many suggested me to press Ctrl + Alt + F5 and Alt + F3. I tried both and I even went further to test any combination of Ctrl, Alt, Fn and F1 to F12. Unfortunately, none of these work for me.

I can afford to lose the data inside my machine, but does replacing a new SSD save the world?

===== 7-July-2023 ====
After leaving my laptop under the desks for years, I still can't find one solution to fix it. I went to local computer store, according to them it was due to the board, not software. So board was changed and I stay with Windows 11 for this laptop.

Comment: Your disk is fine - so you can (at worst) retain all your data files. You should (with care) be able to reload your OS. A current backup of your data to an external disk is strongly advised before you do anything that could endanger your data.